# Some functions are not working after uploading the website to the server

Tags: javascript, html, server, web-hosting

On `localhost` my website is working fine. After uploading it to the hosting server some Functions are not working. Some pictures are not being displayed while others from the same folder are.

But every function is working and every picture is being displayed on `localhost`.

For example, the following code is not working on the server. If you select an image in the input field, it will show you preview of the image

```js
/* The uploader form */
$(function() {
  $(':file').change(function() {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
  });
});

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
  $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
  $('#yourImage').attr('src', e.target.result);
}
```

```css
    /* Image Designing Propoerties */
.thumb {
  height: 75px;
  margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
}
#myImg {
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="thumbnail"></div>
<h5>Upload Your File Here: </h5>
<img id="myImg" src="" >
</br></br>
<input type='file' />
```

Comment: Can you explain what your code is supposed to do?

Comment: it will display preview of image that you select in input

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? The code snippet seems to work fine for what you described.

Comment: no error showing

Comment: and yes everything  working like butter in my localhost

Comment: Are you sure your javascript is in the right location on the server and is accessible?

Comment: have you tried by clearing cache and cookies and then check

Comment: If Javascript code is not working then it should be some error on console.

Comment: other complex javascript code is working